# Rewrite Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, matching, regex-group

I am trying to rewrite this code without the or operator.

```
    if((/^\s*field\s+{\s*$/)||(/^\s*field\s+{\s*\/\/.*$/)
    {
        # Do something
    }
```

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction?  (Would this be homework?)

Comment: You have not provided enough information here.  What criteria do you want to match on? The regex of `/./` would match all of those lines without a '|' operator.

Comment: Not a homework :) I was writing a parser and I wanted to match commented lines. -2 for this ?!

Comment: @alertjean - -3 points, 3 votes to close....and counting.  If you'd bother to explain in plain English what you're actually trying to do, you might be able to get your question answered.  I'd hurry, though, because you likely only have minutes left before this question is closed.

Comment: I would like my regexp to match lines 1,2 & 3 but not lines 4 & 5.

Comment: @alertjean: don't give _examples_ since there are dozens of ways to interpret them. Give the _rules!_

Comment: I am parsing a C++ like file and I want my parser to match both commented and uncommented lines(Single line comments).

Comment: @alertjean - Since there are only three lines of text in your example, `/./` should work (vacuously).

Comment: No..I have edited the question..It shouldn't match line 4 & 5. Or improperly commented lines.

Comment: @alertjean - You gave two blocks of text:  one with three lines and another with two lines.  Please stop being obtuse and explain the rules of exactly what you want matched and what you don't want matched.

Comment: "I am parsing a C++ like file and I want my parser to match both commented and uncommented lines(Single line comments)".  I think this is the best I can explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @JackManey I think what he is trying to say is said more clearly in the part where he says "[It shouldn't match] improperly commented lines."

Comment: Okay, then what constitutes a properly commented line?  What about multi-line comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to rewrite

```
(/^\s*field\s+{\s*$/) || (/^\s*field\s+{\s*\/\/.*$/)
```

Might I suggest:

```
m#^\s*field\s+{\s*($|//)#
```

The last part `($|//)` will look for either of two valid line endings: Just the end of the line, or two slashes. Note that the slashes can be followed by any character, as if you had written `//.*$`.

Comment: There won't be any division operators in this file.

Comment: Well.. this code will do *something*, but I doubt you can get something to do everything, unless you use a more specific tool, like paxdiablo suggests in his latest revision.

Comment: Just gave one more edit to the original question. I guess I was describing an XY problem.

Comment: @alertjean Yes, this is a lot easier to solve. Updated my answer.

Comment: @alertjean If you know about the XY problem, take a look at [The Wrong Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/what-is-a-better-way-to-name-the-wrong-question) =)

Answer (score 2):

Your rules aren't very well specified but you could capture those lines with a simple:

```
^text[1-3]
```

That will get all lines starting with those `textN` words where `N` is one of the set `{1,2,3}`. That seems the most likely based on the fact it's achievable with the regex `|` functionality as well:

```
^(text1|text2|text3)
```

However, as stated, the specs weren't that detailed so we don't really *know* what you want to capture. You should specify the exact *rules* that you need to capture rather than just examples, which can be misinterpreted.

---

Okay, after one of your comments, it begins to make sense:

> I am parsing a C++ like file and I want my parser to match both commented and uncommented lines(Single line comments).

So you're looking for either lines with valid to-end-of-line comments `//` or lines without comments at all.

The key word in your comment is "parse". Seriously, don't try to do this with a regex unless you *know* the code will be *very* simple. If you want to parse, you need a parser. Plain and simple. In fact, even for simple code, I would suggest you should use a parser.

Examples: what will you do with the following perfectly valid lines:

```
int ratio = height
                  /
                   width;
char *description = "This program will look for '//' markers";
int myvar = text1 / comment;
```

---

Assuming that your C++-like language will be *very* simple (for example, no `//` characters other than as comments at the end of a line), you could probably just strip `//.$` off the end of each line in an early pass so that comments are not seen in later passes.

However, this is a fairly tight restriction on your syntax/grammar and, unless you can impose that, a lexer/parser is the best way.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to say that the file has C++ style line comments. There wont be any stray / characters other than for comments.

Comment: @alertjean, you're still probably going to need a parser, so as to handle things like `char *description` in the examples. I'll update the answer with a simplified way of handling your needs with a regex.